# "Vue+S3+Lambda" architecture on Google Cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, google-cloud-platform, serverless-architecture

My single page website (VueJs) has only very few transactions, so I would like to implement it using serverless architecture.

A recommended architecture on AWS for a simple Web Application is the following:

- Vue App uploaded on AWS S3
- Connect to Backend via REST API
- Use Lambda Funktions to connect to a Database

However, I would like to do this on Google Cloud as I plan to use BigQuery for Analytics.

What would be a similar and suitable architecture using Google GCP products to launch my Vue-based website with some straight forward backend processes?

Comment: How far have you investigated and what services have you found that seem suitable or unsuitable…?

Comment: I found suggestions where the Vue App would be in a container and App Engine is being used. However, this looks complicated to me.

I would love to see something like:
Vue -> Cloud Storage (similar S3)
API gateway
Simple Cloud Functions

But I haven't found a source, that confirms that it can be simple like on AWS.

I am well versed with GCP Analytics features, but unfortunately don't know enough other server-less products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

- Cloud Storage for S3
- API Gateway or Cloud Endpoints for REST API (compare your load needs and pricing)
- Cloud functions for lambda

As for implementation complexity it will be more-less same. Some features are implemented in GCP much more convenient than in AWS and some - vice versa.